# Vim with C Conditional Parsing

Tags: c, vim, macros

Does anyone know if Vim has any way to implement C Conditional Parsing like Source Insight?

1. comment out or gray out disabled branch?
2. remove cscope or ctag symbol that in disabled branch?

I've using cscope and ctag with vim to crawl C code. There are a lot of macros, and some code snippets have been disabled by macros.  But Vim displays these snippets in the same color as the others. If the disabled code snippet could be shown greyed-out, that would be more convenient to read.

Also, when I search for a symbol or define with cscope, there are a lot of results, but many of them were already disabled by a macro. Is there any way to filter out disabled results?

Comment: vim will grey out `#if` blocks for constants. It will not expand macro's as it does not contain a c compiler. So... Most likely the answer is no.

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this for vim, it would be very helpful for people how must work with totally macro covered c files like those according AUTOSAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ancient [ifdef highlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=7), you can `:Define` or `:Undefine` preprocessor defines, and the corresponding blocks with be highlighted or not. Apart from that, I'll second @FDinoff's comment: Vim is a *text editor*, and there are no provisions for extending the tags handling and other lookups. Vim only has a basic understanding of a programming language via syntax scripts, not an entire compiler infrastructure like an IDE.

Comment: Actually, I've try ifdef highlighting plugin before, but it's support predefined macro only, it's does not expend the macro, even in same file.
That's why I ask the question. :/